# Remove query scope from auto-loaded resource in Laravel resource controller

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5, if using a resource controller, the model gets loaded automatically and comes through in to the method.
However, I have a query scope checking if my model is active of not. For this one specific case, I'd like to remove that query scope, but leave it on the other methods in the class.

I can see that I can override `resolveRouteBinding` in the model. But that overrides it for all methods, not just the one method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any great way to do this, but here's a solution that should work.

You can use 2 resource route groups:

```php
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController', [
    'parameters' => [
        'photo' => 'photo_no_scope',
    ],
    'only' => ['edit', 'update'],
]);

Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController', [
    'except' => ['edit', 'update'],
]);
```

Then you'll have to instruct Laravel what `photo_no_scope` means. The best place to do this is inside your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        // Include archived photos
        Route::bind('photo_no_scope', function ($id) {
            return Photo::withoutGlobalScopes()->findOrFail($id);
        });
    }
}
```

Haven't tested but you might also have to update your controller to look for a `$photo_no_scope` argument instead of `$photo`

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found the cleanest way was to just use normal routes instead of a resource route when I wanted to remove the global scopes.